# Loading GUI on host machine through SSH with X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, forwarding, x11

I've got applications on my host machine running fine by doing:

```
$ssh -X user@host
Welcome to host
$firefox
```

Firefox proceeds to run in client display from the host machine.

How do I get firefox to load on the host machine's display so I could remotely manage the host machine's running GUI applications?  I need my application to load a GUI on a remote machine without walking to that machine or expecting the user to launch it.

EDIT: Firefox is just an example app, but I am using one machine to launch several trainer programs on remote machines.  Each remote machine will be controlled by a different person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is really a superuser.com question, since there's no programming involved.]

The `-X` flag to ssh is specifically for sending the display back to the machine you
ssh'ed from.   To display on the machine you're ssh'ed to, instead you'd set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to that machines display (probably ":0" but may vary depending on configuration, virtual terminals, etc.), and make sure you have the right authentication
set up to talk to that display (see the [Xsecurity man page](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man7/Xsecurity.7.html) for details).

Comment: I was able to get what I needed by running: --> 
    $ export DISPLAY=:0; 
    $ xhost local:my_username; -->

On one of my machines I had to set the DISPLAY=:2

Comment: @cdated you can just do `$ DISPLAY=:0 xhost local:my_username` in one line if you just have a single command you wish to use the DISPLAY variable for.

Comment: @cdated: "I need my application to load a GUI on a remote machine" - if the GUI should be visible both on the local and remote machine, X forwarding won't do that; what it does is show the GUI of the remote application *only* on the local display.

Comment: @Piskvor: That's fine, I suppose I wasn't clear.  Launching on a server through an ssh session, and gui on a client.  The app can be administered through remote shell even as a separate process so only client GUI is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the application GUI to be visible both on the local and remote machine, then
VNC (plus ssh port forwarding) is the solution you're looking for - try x11vnc or vino. (If you only need the remote application's GUI on local display, then X forwarding is the solution, as outlined in [the other answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/150041/loading-gui-on-host-machine-through-ssh-with-x11-forwarding/150043#150043))

Comment: This would be fine, but I only want/need to send on application GUI not an entire desktop.  Also, I am using one machine terminal to control several application launches at once, which all need independent control over the display application.